Why clang-format add a spacea after 'repeated' keyword in protobuf file?
I am using clang-format to format a protobuf file, and clang-format add a space before dot.
protobuf file:
message Req {
    repeated string IDs = 1 [(validate.rules).repeated.min_items = 1];
}

I imported a third party proto validate https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate, and used clang-format format this proto, I got:
message Req {
    repeated string hotelIDs = 1 [(validate.rules).repeated .min_items = 1];
}  

There is a space between repeated and .min_items, this is why?
My clang-format command:
 clang-format -style="{ IndentWidth: 4, BasedOnStyle: google, AlignConsecutiveAssignments: AcrossEmptyLines, AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: AcrossEmptyLines, ColumnLimit: 1000 }"

I don't want this space, what should I do?

I was able to repeat your finding, but was unable to solve the problem. How many times does the problem occur in your code. Is an exception an option?  Additional note: ColumnLimit: 1000 Don't do that if you want unlimited line width. Use 0 as described in the documentation. And maybe add -language: Proto

@rzickler Thanks for advice, I added Language: Proto and set ColumnLimit: 0, the space dosent disappear. The problem always occur when I check repeated field, and it's an exception for me, I put the proto into Postman and Postman parse failed.

Yes, I wasn't able to fix the issue with those additions either. How many of those repeated fields are there in your code? Just a few or a lot and all over the place? I must add: I'm not a proto expert, and Clang-Format is mainly used for C/C++ formatting.

@rzickler Thank you all the same. I found an issue with the same problem https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54848, and it dosen't look like fixed. I use sed to replace the unexpected space after clang-format now.

The solution with sed is probably currently the best solution.
If the issue is just at some places, you can also do the following:
message Req {
    // clang-format off
    repeated string IDs = 1 [(validate.rules).repeated.min_items = 1];
    // clang-format on
}

This will suppress all formatting between // clang-format off and // clang-format on.
But this is work intensive and not looking nicely, if the issue occurs often. Also, other - maybe desired - formatting is skipped.
